# Etat HTTP 500 - NullPointerException

Tags: java, mysql, servlets, nullpointerexception

i'm getting the above error message when trying to display the User table from MySql DB.
As you can see, the error is generated by the DisplayUsersServlet at line 33 which is the folloxing code : **ArrayList arr = userDb.selectUsers();**

```
java.lang.NullPointerException
        user.DisplayUsersServlet.doGet(DisplayUsersServlet.java:33)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
        javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)






Here are my classes:
```

package business;

```
import java.io.Serializable;

public class User implements Serializable
{
    private String firstName;
    private String lastName;
    private String emailAddress;

    public User()
    {
        firstName = "";
        lastName = "";
        emailAddress = "";
    }

    public User(String first, String last, String email)
    {
        firstName = first;
        lastName = last;
        emailAddress = email;
    }

    public void setFirstName(String f)
    {
        firstName = f;
    }
    public String getFirstName()
    { 
        return firstName; 
    }

    public void setLastName(String l)
    {
        lastName = l;
    }

    public String getLastName()
    { 
        return lastName; 
    }

    public void setEmailAddress(String e)
    {
        emailAddress = e;
    }

    public String getEmailAddress()
    { 
        return emailAddress; 
    }
}
```

Servlet class

```
package user;

import java.io.*;

import javax.servlet.*;
import javax.servlet.http.*;

import java.util.ArrayList;

import business.User;
import data.UserDB;

public class DisplayUsersServlet extends HttpServlet {


    private static final long serialVersionUID = 1L;

    UserDB userDb;

    protected void doGet(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        // TODO: get an ArrayList of User objects from the database

        ArrayList<User> arr = userDb.selectUsers();

        HttpSession session = request.getSession();
        // TODO: set the ArrayList of User objects as a session attribute
        session.setAttribute("users", arr);

        String url = "/users.jsp";
        RequestDispatcher dispatcher = getServletContext()
                .getRequestDispatcher(url);
        dispatcher.forward(request, response);
    }

    protected void doPost(HttpServletRequest request,
            HttpServletResponse response) throws ServletException, IOException {
        doGet(request, response);
    }
}
```

DAO

```
package data;

import java.sql.*;
import java.util.ArrayList;

import business.User;

public class UserDB

{



    // TODO: add code that returns an ArrayList of User objects
            // that corresponds with the rows in the User table
    public ArrayList<User> selectUsers() {

        ConnectionPool pool = ConnectionPool.getInstance();
        Connection connection = pool.getConnection();
        PreparedStatement ps = null;
        ResultSet rs = null;


        String query = "select * from User";
        ArrayList<User> arrUsr = new ArrayList<>();

        try {
            ps = connection.prepareStatement(query);
            rs = ps.executeQuery();
            User user = null;
            while (rs.next()) {

                user = resultSetRowToUsers(rs);

                if (user.getFirstName()!=null)

                    arrUsr.add(resultSetRowToUsers(rs));
            }




        } catch (SQLException e) {
            // TODO Auto-generated catch block
            e.printStackTrace();
        }

        return arrUsr;


    }


     public User resultSetRowToUsers(ResultSet resultSet) throws SQLException {

        //User user = new User();
        return new User(resultSet.getString(1), resultSet.getString(2),
                resultSet.getString(3));

    }

}
```

Print StackTrace (Eclipse console)

```
Jul 11, 2013 2:12:53 PM org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve invoke
SEVERE: "Servlet.service()" for servlet DisplayUsersServlet has generated an exception
java.lang.NullPointerException
    at user.DisplayUsersServlet.doGet(DisplayUsersServlet.java:33)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:621)
    at javax.servlet.http.HttpServlet.service(HttpServlet.java:728)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.internalDoFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:305)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.ApplicationFilterChain.doFilter(ApplicationFilterChain.java:210)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardWrapperValve.invoke(StandardWrapperValve.java:222)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardContextValve.invoke(StandardContextValve.java:123)
    at org.apache.catalina.authenticator.AuthenticatorBase.invoke(AuthenticatorBase.java:472)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardHostValve.invoke(StandardHostValve.java:171)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.ErrorReportValve.invoke(ErrorReportValve.java:99)
    at org.apache.catalina.valves.AccessLogValve.invoke(AccessLogValve.java:947)
    at org.apache.catalina.core.StandardEngineValve.invoke(StandardEngineValve.java:118)
    at org.apache.catalina.connector.CoyoteAdapter.service(CoyoteAdapter.java:408)
    at org.apache.coyote.http11.AbstractHttp11Processor.process(AbstractHttp11Processor.java:1009)
    at org.apache.coyote.AbstractProtocol$AbstractConnectionHandler.process(AbstractProtocol.java:589)
    at org.apache.tomcat.util.net.JIoEndpoint$SocketProcessor.run(JIoEndpoint.java:312)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor.runWorker(Unknown Source)
    at java.util.concurrent.ThreadPoolExecutor$Worker.run(Unknown Source)
    at java.lang.Thread.run(Unknown Source)
```

Comment: userDb is not initialized, so userDb.selectUsers(); can't work. You need to initialized userDb or make selectUsers() static so you can make UserDB.selectUsers().

Answer (score 2, accepted):

userDb needs to be initialized?

Comment: You're right. I just initialized it and i'm getting a different error now but it looks much better. Thank you. I'll vote for u ;).

Answer (score 1):

Your `userDb` instance variable is `null`. It isn't instantiated nor injected, so it will keep its default value of `null`.

Either instantiate it yourself, or (if you're using Servlet spec 3) have it injected.

Comment: line 33 is ArrayList<User> arr = userDb.selectUsers();

Answer (score 1):

You should insert a comment into your code pointing out where line 33 is.  However, I would guess that the `userDb` variable is never initialized.  You aren't using any form of dependency injection, and nothing ever assigns to it, so it remains null.

By the way, GETs and POSTs are different things.  Don't have one call the other.

Comment: Absolutely, the Post methods that have to call the other is a bad practice. i'll fix it. Thank you so much